# Can I remove the datalist dropdown menu before I start typing?

Tags: html

I'm setting up a makeshift search bar on my website that lists the results in a dropdown menu. According to my knowledge, the easiest way to do that is using a datalist. But how can I prevent the dropdown menu (that contains all the possible keywords) to show up before the user starts typing in the search box?

I currently have the following set up:

```
<input type="text" list="options" placeholder="Search">

<datalist id="options">
  <option value="Foo">
  <option value="Bar">
</datalist>
```

By default, when you click inside the input field, the list shows up, but I would like to have that hidden until the user starts typing data. Only then should the dropdown menu be shown.

Comment: It's possible to use dropdown, use Jquery to populate the dropdown by the data you want to add. Also in Jquery you can easily hide and show tag elements. [link](https://jquery.com/)

Comment: You mean to use a normal dropdown list?

Comment: Yeah, a normal dropdown list.

Comment: Well, I would like for the user to be able to type their own text as well and not be confined to only the options I present to them.